# GWT Guice + RPC Service getting 404 Not Found

Tags: java, gwt, firebug, guice, rpc

I am getting a 404 Not found Exception when my service is being accessed...I'm adding a very simple servlet to a GWT Guice webapp...I'm using RPC for my servlet implementation.

**Update (I'm still getting the same problems below with my changes): I realized I may need a binding in the ServletModule class, so I added this:

```
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(BCDWebImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    serve("/a-bcd/abcd/bcdWebUtil").with(BCDWebImpl.class);
```

I also added a Window.alert(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()) to my code, this outputs:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/a-bcd/abcd/
```

This is the output I'm getting from firebug:

```
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic YWxsVXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  148
Content-Type    text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=97FA0BE47F77E170C18B105C509F980D
Host    xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/a-bcd/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
X-GWT-Module-Base   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/a-bcd/abcd/
X-GWT-Permutation   35D972F27B5773A4C5ACAFE8EA5C1F36
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BCDWebImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pz.abcd.server.rest.BCDWebImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BCDWebImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/a-bcd/abcd/BCDWeb</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

BCDWeb Class:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("bcdWeb")
public interface BCDWeb extends RemoteService
{
  public String getName ();
}
```

gwt.xml:

```
<module rename-to='abcd'>
    <servlet class="com.pz.abcd.server.rest.BCDWebImpl" path="/bcdWeb" />
```

BCDEntryPoint.java:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // This is required for Gwt-Platform proxy's generator
    DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector);        

    ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();
    setUpEnv();

}

private void setUpEnv(){
    BCDWebAsync web = GWT.create(BCDWeb.class);
    ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget)web;
    endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "bcdWeb");
    web.getName(new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            GWT.log(caught.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String name) {
            // do something here;  
        }
    });
}
```

Again, this webapp is using guice, but I'm trying to add on a very simple RPC servlet...any ideas what could be the problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use [Guice Servlets](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) and/or have you set the `GuiceFilter` in `web.xml`?

Comment: Yes, the webapp does use Guice Servlets, and GuiceFilter is set in the web.xml.  Although I am just trying to add on a simple RPC servlet...I'm wondering if this isn't possible because of the Guice setup...

Comment: are there any other special configurations I do when adding an RPC servlet in a guice set up?  I tried adding a binding to the ServletModule class, but that didn't change my error. I also added an @Singleton annotation to my BCDWebImpl class...still didn't work.

Comment: 1) If you use Guice Servlet, you don't need to declare anything in your web.xml (except for the guicy things); just use your mapping in `configureServlets()`. 2) You don't need to declare the servlet in your module. 3) You don't need to use `ServiceDefTarget` in your `setUpEnv()`, just rely `on @RemoteServiceRelativePath("bcdWeb")` which is already relative to your `abcd` module. 4) Typo: `bcdWebUtil` (in the `serve()`) vs `bcdWeb` (in the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath`). Can't say much more.

Answer (score 0):

URL patterns are case sensitive

You given in `web.xml`

```
<url-pattern>/a-bcd/abcd/BCDWeb</url-pattern>
                            ^____
                                 |
 @RemoteServiceRelativePath("bcdWeb");   //and using the path in small letters.
```

Try to change the pattern as

```
<url-pattern>/a-bcd/abcd/bcdWeb</url-pattern>
```

Comment: try to give full path  `@RemoteServiceRelativePath(a-bcd/abcd/bcdWeb)`